# TIFF image Rotation Using PHP

Tags: php, image, rotation, tiff

My Problem is:

I want to upload the tiff image and then i want to rotate that image automatically such that it is oriented correctly . And then user can download that correctly oriented tiff image.
I want to use PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried using image rotate function and exif but its not working for me. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Without lib i don't think it's possible because tiff is an adobe format.
I think you should use command line of gimp with parameters or with another program like photoshop and save your image after oriented.

With php and exec function i think perhaps it's possible.